# Disable local echo in client from a telnet server

Tags: telnet

I'm developing a Telnet server for my new project and I'd like to know what's the characters sequence to disable local echo, to securely type a password. I've tried \xff\xfb\x01 and all those escape sequences but none of them have worked. Please help.

Thanks,

Pedro Franceschi

Answer (score 1):

How about sending a backspace and '*' for each password character? It may still show each character briefly which isn't necessarily a bad thing. [I like how the iPhone shows just the last typed character so I didn't mistype it without leaving the whole password on-screen.] Not quite what you asked, but perhaps a usable alternative.

Comment: That's a nice idea. I'll try to implement it. PS: how do I send a backspace?